# Getting counts based on status of the record rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, unique

I have a scenario where I have to show the count of the total enrolled people for a process. There are two statuses inprogress and completed. The person can enroll the process multiple times and for each time we are tracking the person in a table called process_people. Each process people record may be in different step of a process.

Lets say person A enters the process A and completed the process and same person enters again and be the part of the process(in progress).

What I need is I need to get the unique total enrolled people count, I can get that using the below,

```
unique_count = ProcessPerson.where(status: %[completed inprogress]).select(:person_id).distinct.count
```

The requirement is to show the unique active people count, which should also be unique count. If a person completed the same process and inprogress in the same process means we need to skip them in active people count. The count of person who is in progress for a process and not completed the same process before is the expected result.

Total enrolled people = unique(inprogress people + Completed people)

Active people = unique(who is in progress and not completed the same process before)

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this query:

```sql
SELECT grouped_process_people.* 
FROM (
  SELECT ordered_process_people.* 
  FROM (
    SELECT process_id, people_id, status 
    FROM scratch.process_people 
    ORDER BY (status = 'completed') DESC , status /* (1) */
    ) as ordered_process_people 
  GROUP BY process_id, people_id /* (2) */
) as grouped_process_people 
WHERE status <> 'completed'; /* (3) */
```

What's going on in that SQL (use the numbers next to the sub-queries), say your table looks like this:

```sql
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
| id | process_id | people_id |   status   |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         11 |        21 | inprogress |
|  2 |         11 |        21 | completed  |
|  3 |         11 |        21 | inprogress |
|  4 |         12 |        21 | inprogress |
|  5 |         12 |        21 | inprogress |
|  6 |         12 |        21 | inprogress |
|  7 |         13 |        23 | inprogress |
|  8 |         13 |        23 | completed  |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
```

1. Order the table so that the rows with status as completed are on the top.

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| process_id | people_id | status     |
+------------+-----------+------------+
|         11 |        21 | completed  |
|         13 |        23 | completed  |
|         11 |        21 | inprogress |
|         11 |        21 | inprogress |
|         12 |        21 | inprogress |
|         12 |        21 | inprogress |
|         12 |        21 | inprogress |
|         13 |        23 | inprogress |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

2. Group by `process_id` and `people_id` so that only a unique combination of these pairs are selected, with the ones that have status as completed, marked so.

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| process_id | people_id | status     |
+------------+-----------+------------+
|         11 |        21 | completed  |
|         12 |        21 | inprogress |
|         13 |        23 | completed  |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

3. Now, since we only want the ones that are not completed, the third and the outermost query, would filter out the ones that have status as completed.

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| process_id | people_id | status     |
+------------+-----------+------------+
|         12 |        21 | inprogress |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

The way to run this query would be to store it as a string, for example if it were stored in a variable called `active_people_process_query`, then it would be run like so:

```rb
ProcessPerson.find_by_sql(active_people_process_query)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, _status_ column must be handled in the GROUP BY clause in step (2), did you tried it?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question Ahmed. I've tried this, and the query works. Let me know if you think this might fail for a certain edge case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done in one step (one query) , but what i think of :

- First we group by person_id & process_id

  ```
  step_1 = ProcessPerson.all.select(:person_id, :process_id, :status).group_by{ |pp| [pp.person_id, pp.process_id]}
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  {
    [5, 5]=> [
      {person_id: 5, process_id: 5, status: "completed"},
      {person_id: 5, process_id: 5, status: "inprogress"}
    ],
    [4, 1]=>[
      {person_id: 4, process_id: 1, status: "completed"},
      {person_id: 4, process_id: 1, status: "inprogress"}
    ],
    [6, 5]=>[
      {person_id: 6, process_id: 5, status: "completed"}
    ],
    [2, 5]=>[
      {person_id: 2, process_id: 5, status: "completed"}
    ],
    [6, 2]=>[
      {person_id: 6, process_id: 2, status: "inprogress"}
    ],
    [2, 2]=>[
      {person_id: 2, process_id: 2, status: "completed"}
    ],
    [5, 3]=>[
      {person_id: 5, process_id: 3, status: "inprogress"}
    ],
    [3, 4]=>[
      {person_id: 3, process_id: 4, status: "completed"}
    ]
  }
  ```
- Then we select any groups that is inprogress AND not have completed process

  ```
  step_2 = step_1.filter{ |k, v| v.any? {|h| h[:status] == "inprogress" } && !v.any? {|h| h[:status] == "completed" } }
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  {
    [6, 2]=>[
      {person_id: 6, process_id: 2, status: "inprogress"}
    ],
    [5, 3]=>[
      {person_id: 5, process_id: 3, status: "inprogress"}
    ]
  }
  ```
- Then we count the Result

  ```
  step_3 = step_2.count
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  2
  ```